# How to add a default port number defined in program to getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I want to define a port number in my header (like `#define port 9191`) and use it to call `getaddrinfo()`. But i am getting an error since the parameter service is a `char const*`. How do I use a `#define`d port number in a call to `getaddrinfo()`?

Below I `#define`d port as `9191` and tried to convert it into a `char*` using `sprintf()`. Then I tried to use it in a call to `getaddrinfo()`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 9191 // here the define port number
#define LEN 500

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    struct sockaddr_in cliAddr;  // the from address of a client
    int sock, s, clilen;
    char *service; // declared variable name
    struct sockaddr_in storage;

    ssize_t n;
    char receive[LEN], message[LEN];
    sprintf(service, "%d", PORT); // i have tried convert it to char

    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s \n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0;    /* For wildcard IP address */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, &service, &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
       Try each address until we successfully bind(2).
       If socket(2) (or bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
       and) try the next address. */

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
            rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1)
            continue;

        if (bind(sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;                  /* Success */

        close(sock);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */

    /* Read datagrams and echo them back to sender */

    while (1)
    {
        //bzero(receive, LEN);
        clilen = sizeof(cliAddr);
        n = recvfrom(sock, receive, strlen(receive), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, &clilen);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error in reading\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("The client message: %s\n ", receive);
        bzero(message, LEN);

        fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);

        message[LEN] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", message);
        n = sendto(sock, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, sizeof(cliAddr));
        printf("%ld\n", n);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error in replying\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        int i = strncmp("Exit", receive, 4);
        if (i == 0)
            break;

        printf("The server message: %s\n", message);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char *service; // declared variable name
> // ...
> sprintf(service, "%d", PORT); // i have tried convert it to char
> ```

Since `service` is uninitialized and most likely contains an invalid pointer value, the call to `sprintf()` causes undefined behaviour.

Either allocate memory on the free-store and have `service` pointing to it or use an array of sufficient size.

Answer (score 1):

As [Swordfish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52885164/1475978) already answered, you are trying to `sprintf()` to an undefined pointer. Use for example

```
#define  STRINGIFY_(x)  #x
#define  STRINGIFY(x)   STRINGIFY_(x)

service = STRINGIFY(PORT);
```

instead.

---

Consider the following helper function:

```
#define  DEFAULT_HOST "*"
#define  DEFAULT_PORT "9191"

/* Return a server-side UDP/IP(v4/v6) socket bound
   to the specified address. If addr is non-NULL,
   and *addrlen is initialized to its length and
   is large enough, the bound-to address will be
   stored there.  Returns -1 with errno set if
   an error occurs. */       
int server_socket(struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen,
                  const char *host, const char *port)
{
    struct addrinfo  hints, *list, *curr;
    int              err, fd;

    /* Set defaults, if NULL or empty. */
    if (!host || !*host)
        host = DEFAULT_HOST;
    if (!port || !*port)
        port = DEFAULT_PORT;

    /* "" or "*" host refer to wildcard address. */
    if (!host[0] || !strcmp(host, "*")
        host = NULL;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;       /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;  /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0;              /* For wildcard IP address */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;           /* Any protocol */
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    err = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &list);
    if (err)
        switch (err) {
        case EAI_ADDRFAMILY:
        case EAI_FAMILY:
            errno = EAFNOSUPPORT;
            return -1;
        case EAI_AGAIN:
            errno = EAGAIN;
            return -1;
        case EAI_FAIL:
        case EAI_NODATA:
        case EAI_NONAME:
        case EAI_SERVICE:
            errno = EADDRNOTAVAIL;
            return -1;
        case EAI_MEMORY:
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return -1;
        case EAI_SOCKTYPE:
            errno = ESOCKTNOSUPPORT;
            return -1;
        case EAI_SYSTEM:
            /* errno already set */
            return -1;
        default:
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }

    /* Find first valid socket we can construct and bind to */
    for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->ai_next) {
        fd = socket(curr->ai_family, curr->ai_socktype, curr->ai_protocol);
        if (fd == -1)
            continue;

        if (bind(fd, curr->ai_addr, curr->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break; /* This one works. */

        /* Cannot bind. Clean it up, and try the next one. */
        close(fd);
    }

    if (!curr) {
        /* No suitable socket found. */
        errno = EADDRNOTAVAIL;
        return -1;
    }       

    /* Copy bound-to address, if enough room */
    if (addrlen) {
        if (!addr || *addrlen < curr->ai_addrlen) {
            *addrlen = 0;
        } else {
            memcpy(addr, curr->ai_addr, curr->ai_addrlen);
            *addrlen = curr->ai_addrlen;
        }
    }

    /* Discard the linked list getaddrinfo() provided. */
    freeaddrinfo(list);

    return fd;
}
```

Both numeric ports and named services (as listed in `getent services`) can be used for both the default port and the port parameter.

A typical service would read those from a configuration file (or files).

If the above `server_socket()` fails, it will return -1 with `errno` approximating the error message. (If `getaddrinfo()` fails, it maps the error to `errno` constants as best as it can, instead of using `gai_strerror()`.)
If it succeeds, it will return the descriptor number of the bound socket.

The reason you'll want to write these as separate functions, is mainly *laziness and ease of maintenance*. You see, if you write the above (with the necessary #includes and so on) into a separate test program, you can test this part separately, as an unit: thus, [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) it with a few different parameters, including NULL pointers and invalid values.  Use e.g.

```
struct sockaddr_storage  addr;
socklen_t                addrlen;
const char              *node, *service;
int                      fd;

addrlen = sizeof addr;
fd = server_socket(&addr, &addrlen, node, service);
if (fd == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create server socket: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

to report the errors.  Remember that testing is not just checking if the function works when given sane parameters; it is also testing what happens if the parameters themselves are wrong/bad/contradictory etc., and verifying that *that* too is acceptable.

The reason this kind of piecewise testing saves time and effort is that *when* bugs occur -- and they will, no matter how good a programmer you are --, there is only a small part of the code (the added parts not yet unit tested) and their overall interaction logic (the "higher level" logic), that you need to examine and think about to find the bugs.  Plus, you don't need to waste brainpower in trying to keep all parts of the code in your mind at the same time; you can just forget about the unit-tested parts, only remembering what they do in general terms.

This also means you'll want to learn to write comments that describe what *your intent* as a programmer is that the code should do, rather than what the code does.  The latter is obvious from the code, but only the programmer knows the former; to efficiently find bugs, we need to know both.  (I'm still learning this part myself, after over two decades of paid programming work.)